# When i trying to open VScode by .code command in window 11 , then getting this error

Tags: visual-studio-code

[0204/044735.409:FATAL:v8_initializer.cc(525)] Error loading V8 startup snapshot file

Comment: Exact version info of your Windows build and VS Code installation please.

Comment: Also, is that the full error message or just one line of it? If not the full message, show the actual full error message.

Comment: [Similar GitHub issue ticket: \#165484 (windows 10)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/165484). User solved by re-installing VS Code. Have you tried re-installing VS Code?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue here. I don´t know why, but after the latest VS Code release, a folder was created in my VS Code folder (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code) called "_". I copied everything from this folder and pasted it into the VS Code folder and the error disappeared. Try this too and see if solves the problem